# Autocomplete jQuery with Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I want to retrive data from a json file using Jquery autocomplete and ajax call in Wordpress.

This is my code:

HTLM

```
<div class="form-group formComuni">
    <label for="input-button" class="sr-only">Inserisci il nome del tuo Comune</label>
    <div class="input-group inputComuni">
        <input name="search" id="comuni" class="form-control large-input align-middle" type="text" placeholder="Inserisci il nome del tuo Comune"><i class="fas fa-search fa-lg"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

JSON

```
{"comuni":[{"datapresub":"01/02/2000","datasub":"01/02/2018","nomeComune":"ROMA","provincia":"RM"},{"nomeComune":"ROMAGNANO AL MONTE","provincia":"SA"},{"nomeComune":"ROMAGNANO SESIA","provincia":"NO"},{"nomeComune":"ROMAGNESE","provincia":"PV"},{"nomeComune":"ROMANA","provincia":"SS"},{"nomeComune":"ROMANENGO","provincia":"CR"},{"nomeComune":"ROMANO CANAVESE","provincia":"TO"},{"nomeComune":"ROMANO D'EZZELINO","provincia":"VI"},{"nomeComune":"ROMANO DI LOMBARDIA","provincia":"BG"},{"nomeComune":"ROMANS D'ISONZO","provincia":"GO"},{"nomeComune":"ROMBIOLO","provincia":"VV"},{"nomeComune":"ROMENO","provincia":"TN"},{"nomeComune":"ROMENTINO","provincia":"NO"},{"nomeComune":"ROMETTA","provincia":"ME"}]}
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    $( "#comuni" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: ajaxUrl,
                data: {
                    action: "mon_action"
                },
                success: function(data) {
                response( $.map(data, function(item) {
                    return item.nomeComune;
                }));
            }
            });
        },
        minLength: 3,
    });
}
```

PHP

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_mon_action', 'mon_action' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_mon_action', 'mon_action' );

function mon_action() {

    $request = wp_remote_get( "https://demo.ec2webdesign.com/anpr-dev/rom.json", array(
        'headers' => array('Content-Type' => 'application/json;')
    ) );

    if( is_wp_error( $request ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );
    $data = json_decode( $body );
    echo json_encode($data->comuni);
    echo ($body);
}
```

Something is wrong on my code. I need the autocomplete based on "nomeComune".

In console I got this warning:

```
TypeError: cannot use 'in' operator to search for "length" in "[{\"datapresub\":\"..."
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think for a moment about what you are doing here how it is supposed to work:

```
$(function(){
    $( "#comuni" ).autocomplete({
       source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: ajaxUrl,
                    data: {
                    action: "mon_action"
                     },
                    success: function(data) {
                    response( $.map(data, function(item) {
                        return item.nomeComune;
                     }));
                 }
               });
            },
       minLength: 3,
}
```

According to [jQuery documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) passing anonymous function to *source* option of autocomplete gives you possibility to filter suggestions based on current value of given input (stored in request.term property) by doing your custom request.  
It seems though, that you just want to fetch your json once and use it as source. 
In order to do so you need to move your invocation of jQuery.autocomplete function to success callback of "mon_action" backend API endpoint.

```
 $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: ajaxUrl,
         data: {
           action: "mon_action"
          },
          success: function(data) {
              $( "#comuni" ).autocomplete({
               // TODO: parse data properly
               source: data
             })
         }
       });
```

Luckily there is another error in your code, luckily, because otherwise autocompletion would work and you wouldn't notice, that there are hundreds of unnecessary requests. 
You don't want to map data directly (which is JSON object, so you cannot map it), you want to map "comuni" property of your data, which is an array.

```
$.map(data.comuni, function(item) {
     return item.nomeComune;
    })
```